# Multisite domain mapping breaks CSS

Tags: multisite, css, domain-mapping

I have set up a multisite (sub directories) and all my plugins/CSS was working fine.
Then I added domain mapping and managed to point a domain `example.com` to a site ID 4.
All still working fine.

However, when I make `example.com` for site ID 4 'primary', the CSS seems to break. My plugins (e.g. responsive slider) no longer works, my CSS also. The moment I un-check the 'primary', all seems to work fine.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: How did you go with this user32062?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just ran into this same issue and found the problem: the MU Domain Mapping plugin is using a deprecated constant, PLUGINDIR, to remap the plugin directories on the mapped domains.

The plugin seems to be very vaguely developed nowadays (and no releases have been out for a year), so I just edited my copy of the plugin directly. In `domain_mapping.php` for the `domain_mapping_plugins_uri()` function (around line 650), short-circuit that function by just returning `$full_url` without running through its other routines.

This should fix the problem.

Comment: the domain mapping plugin should be considered deprecated in my experiance as well

Comment: Yes, agree! It definitely needs some attention to bring it up-to-date with modern WP. Fortunately, my use case is only for dev domains (production won't need it), but others aren't so fortunate.

Comment: @TimMalone I also use the DM plugin for development too. It's very useful in this regard.

Answer (score -2):

Check out these instructions, [Debugging a WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_a_WordPress_Network). That kind of problem is usually caused by a configuration error in the .htaccess file. Check also this page, [Multisite configuration fails with css/js files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77818/multisite-configuration-fails-with-css-js-files)

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer. An answer should give a "solution", suggesting additional debuging steps belongs to comments