# Multisite network on new domain

Tags: multisite, migration

I recently moved my new multisites network (which worked perfectly fine on an old domain) to my new domain. Now the website doesnt seem to work. The homepage doesnt load all images and even the menu isnt being loaded. Even after search and replacing my entire database and removing all the old url instances didnt work. I tried turning the wordpress debug-mode on. But no errors are displayed. When I check my console this is what I see:

[image]

Besides this there is another issue. My dashboard page isn't loading it's CSS. This is what it looks like at the moment : 
[image]

I tried to do the same and check if any errors were logged to the console, but in this case no errors are being logged. Has anyone ever had this situation ? I've moved many websites to new domains but I never had a situation like this before. I ran out of ideas, I hope someone has a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps. It is about an htaccess code problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77818/multisite-configuration-fails-with-css-js-files

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to change `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');` to your new domain name in your **wp-config.php** file

Comment: I already did this.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the wp-options table for the correct URL for your site - in two places.

And then I would use a search/replace plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace", but there are others) to make changes to the URLs in the databases.

This is what needs to be done on any domain move of a WordPress site.

Comment: Yeah i did this first, and when it didnt work i did the search and replace.

Comment: Next step is to look at the Network tab in Developer Tools (usually F12) to see if there is a request for the JS file, and if the request has a status of 200 ("I got it"). If a 400 response, then look at the full URL specified (hover over the JS file to get the full URL) and see if that is valid (try it in another window). If not valid, then do a text search in plugins and themes folder for that JS file string to find the bad code. Then go after the plugin/theme (on their support forum) to get the problem fixed. Or deactivate the plugin and/or try one of the 'twenty' themes.